# What is the difference between proguard-android.txt and proguard-rules.pro ? - Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

In my `buildType` I see this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

I have some questions:

1. Why there are two files?
2. What is the difference between them?
3. Where should I write my rules?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> The `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` method obtains
>   the default ProGuard settings from the Android SDK `tools/proguard/`
>   folder. The `proguard-android-optimize.txt` file is also available in
>   this Android SDK folder with the same rules but with optimizations
>   enabled. ProGuard optimizations perform analysis at the bytecode
>   level, inside and across methods to help make your app smaller and run
>   faster. Android Studio adds the `proguard-rules.pro` file at the root
>   of the module, so you can also easily add custom ProGuard rules
>   specific to the current module.

Please refer this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Meaning that you should add your custom proguard file into `proguard-rules.pro`,if you want to separate some rules to many files,you can do it and declare them after this:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: If your open proguard-android.txt, you will find the following information: `This file is no longer maintained and is not used by new (2.2+) versions of the
# Android plugin for Gradle. Instead, the Android plugin for Gradle generates the
# default rules at build time and stores them in the build directory.`

Comment: They inexplicably removed that paragraph from the documentation. Thank goodness you copy pasted it here.

Answer (score 7):

The `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` will retrieve the ProGuard settings that are stored in the `Android SDK` in `tools/proguard`

The `proguard-rules.pro` is a file that is located at the root of the module. The purpose is to allow you to add custom rules (ProGuard) that are specific to the module.

For more [Information](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are still mostly right, but since they were written some things have changed.

If you open `<android-sdk-root>/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt` then you'll see this comment:

> This file is no longer maintained and is not used by new (2.2+) versions of the Android plugin for Gradle. Instead, the Android plugin for Gradle generates the default rules at build time and stores them in the build directory.

### What does this mean exactly?

It means that the `sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt` file is irrelevant - the rules written inside it are not actually used. However, it does NOT mean that the line `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` is now useless.

If you use `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` with AGP version 2.2 or higher (which I think is everyone at this point), then the `proguard-android.txt` file used will be the one that ships inside AGP itself. Google mention this in the [release notes for AGP 2.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/past-releases/past-agp-releases/agp-2-2-0-release-notes):

> getDefaultProguardFile now returns the default ProGuard files that Android plugin for Gradle provides and no longer uses the ones in the Android SDK.

### How can I see the rules?

If you want to see what rules are applied in the new `proguard-android.txt` file from within AGP, then you can check the `proguard-android.txt` file that AGP generates when it builds your project. Be aware that this file is only generated when minify runs: therefore this file won't exist in your project until you build your project in a build variant with `minifyEnabled` set to `true`. AGP will generate the file in your project in the `<project-root>/build/intermediates/default_proguard_files/global/` directory.

### What if I can't find the file?

Then you can take the hard route and see how the `proguard-android.txt` file is generated by looking at the AGP source code. The following instructions are what worked for me for version 3.0.0:

##### 1 - Find the gradle source files

For this I followed this brilliant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44122888/6007104

To summarise:

- Open the directory `gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/gradle-core/` on your machine
- In here are listed the downloaded AGP versions - open the directory you're interested in
- Dig around within this directory for a file named `gradle-core-X-sources.jar`, where X is the version you want. For me that was `gradle-core-3.0.0-sources.jar`.
- Copy that jar file somewhere safe, and then unzip it to see the AGP source files hidden inside.

##### 2 - Find the rules

Now you have the source files, you might think it's as simple as finding the file named `proguard-android.txt`. Unfortunately, that file doesn't exist - it's dynamically built. Instead, you'll want to find the code within the AGP source where the `proguard-android.txt` file is built. For me that was in `com/android/build/gradle/ProguardFiles.java`. It turns out that (at time of writing), the rules of `proguard-android.txt` are just the rules defined in the `com/android/build/gradle/proguard-common.txt` file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now (July 2023). Instead of taking the hard route to view the elusive `proguard-android.txt`, can I simply ignore it and override it with my own `proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'` statement in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely do that - just be aware that the rules from 'proguard-android.txt' won't be included when proguard runs - it will only use the rules from your custom 'proguard.cfg' file