# How to change Android Studio's default build flavor?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I got a project configured with multiple variants and flavors:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
    }
    release {
    }
}
flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    mock {
    }
    alpha {
    }
    beta {
    }
    prod {
    }
}
```

Whenever I open the project from another one (so starting Android Studio), it selects the `mockDebug` variant by default. Often I end up build this one first, then realizing I'm on the wrong variant.

Is there a way to tell Android Studio to **defaults** to one variant, let's say `betaDebug`?

Technicals: Android Studio 3.1.4, Gradle wrapper 4.4, Android Gradle 3.1.4.

Comment: If this is duplicated please flag.

Comment: doesn't it remember the last/recent variant you built when re-opening studio ?

Comment: Not the last one used, no. See the (simple) accepte asnwer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the order in which you define them in productFlavors. The IDE always loads the first flavor it finds there as the default.

Comment: Silly of me. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case for me - my `Build Variants` list is just alphanumerically sorted. Changing the order in the `productFlavors` block doesn't affect it. This is for Android Studio 3.1.3, at least.

Answer (score 33):

With Android Studio [3.5+](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36988145) you can set default falvors:

```
android {
  flavorDimensions "stage", "target"
  productFlavors {
    develop {
      getIsDefault().set(true) // that does the magic
      dimension "stage"
      ...
```

When using KTS it lookes like this:

```
android {
  flavorDimensions("stage", "target")
  productFlavors {
    create("develop") {
      isDefault = true
      dimension("stage")
      ...
```

Comment: How did you find out? Looked in source? Just curious how people do it first time =)

Comment: @MaksimTuraev Most probably from [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36988145), referenced in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37912981/1233652).

Comment: @MaksimTuraev I actually check the sources (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44122888/3660290) every now and then. But the easiest way is to switch to KTS, since the type-safe accessors offer autocompletion.

Comment: For the Groovy file "getIsDefault().set(true)" can be replaced by "isDefault true".

Answer (score 0):

What actually worked for me is enabling "Android Studio Preferences -> Experimental -> Only sync the active variant". It keeps the selected build variant when reopening AS or when re-syncing, basically solving the original problem.

AS/AGP v4.1.